# Cannot erase an internal SSD drive on Macbook Pro on High Sierra 10.13.6

Tags: macos, ssd

[image]I bought this Mac second hand a while ago and it seems that there is still some hidden files in the drive that take a lot of my space

I have done my backup
I want to completely format and reinstall the OS

I have tried in Terminal, but it keeps on giving me errors 
I am not very advanced in there, but can follow a few commands just to get this sorted

Here is a screen shot of my diskutil list
Also, I only have around 4GB of space left...

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  Super details. Apple has an erace + reinstall process that doesn’t even require a working drive. Would you be interested in that?

Comment: There are no hidden files. Your listing is pretty standard. You have a 250GB disk and your main disk "Andrian" is almost full. The other 3 partitions in disk1 are all standard and have standard sizes.

Comment: How do I format it,though. It keeps on giving me different errors...

Comment: Are you sure the Mac is not full of local snapshots? What does `tmutil listlocalsnapshots /` show?